# TPL can used for sequential scenario

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have sequential steps needs to be executed..lets say:

step1--once it is done--execute step2

step2--once it is done--execute step3

step3--once it is done--execute step4

step4--once it is done--execute step5

step5

These steps need to be executed without UI blocking(calling async)..
Need your suggestion how this can be done using TPL-task parallel library

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235663)():

```
Task t1 = new Task(...);
Task t2 = t1.ContinueWith(()=>{ ... });
Task t3 = t2.ContinueWith(()=>{ ... });
Task t4 = t3.ContinueWith(()=>{ ... });
Task t5 = t4.ContinueWith(()=>{ ... });

t1.Start();
```